# Problem in regex for decimal number

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex for decimal numbers like **00.0**

I tried this `[0-9]{1,2}(.[0-9]{1})?` which works perfectly.

But I have to add **^** at begining and ***$** at end.

Is there any way to have the regex work as the one working along with adding these characters?

^([0-9]{1,2}(.[0-9]{1})?)*$  --> fails to do what I want.

My regex should look like ^[Anything here]*$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `.*$` at the end?  You should probably escape the '`.`' too: your perfect match probably matches `00/0` and `00x0`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - yes *$ at the end and ^ at the begining. Anything in between.

Comment: Are you trying to match a literal `^` at the beginning and a literal `*$` at the end? Like strings of the form `^00.0*$`?

Comment: Not an answer but your regex could be rewritten like [0-9]{1,2}(.[0-9])? {1} is unecessary in this case.

Comment: @eldarerathis - no I am simply matching strings of the form 00.0, but those characters are unknowingly added by the API i am using.

Comment: What type of regex is it? Posix, posix extended, perl, python, emacs, ...?

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin - I am using JAVA language to match string.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - The problem I figured out is of * writing at the end, Is there any way to neglect that? I mean writing anything before *

Comment: @niksvp: It sounds like the API is pretty broken. Does it wrap the entire expression in `()` before adding the leading `^` and ending `*$`? Your example seems to indicate it does.

Comment: @eldarerathis - nicely judged, No it wasn't wrapping entire expression in (), but I got hint thru it. I would have accepted it if you would have posted it in answer. Thank You. +1 to your comment

Comment: So, something is just adding stuff arbitrarily to your regexes?  Why are you letting it do that?  Can't you write them directly in Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem was * and it could be excluded by adding a pair of parenthesis before * like `()*`

And `^([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9])?)()*$` works well.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of regex, but for many regex types (posix, posix extended, perl, python, emacs) `.` (dot) means match any symbol. To match the dot symbol you need to quote it like `\.`.

And to match exactly one digit you don't need to add `{1}` at the end of it. I.e. `[0-9]{1}` is the same as `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thats all true and known to me, but what I need is regex with literals in beginning and end as said above

Answer (score 1):

I think you need .* at the end

but could you reply with some examples of strings you want to match and ones you don't want to match>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you need, have a try with :

```
\^\d\d?(\.\d)?\*\$
```

This will match

```
\^       a carret ^
\d\d?    1 or 2 digit
(\.\d)?  eventually a dot and a digit
\*       an asterisk
\$       a dollar
```

Comment: can you plz tell what is use of ^ and $ in regex?

Comment: `^` means the begining of the line and `$` means end of line. So if you want to match these characters, you have to escape them. Additionnaly `*` means 0 or more times the preceding (group of) character(s).

Comment: Thank you for explaination, I found solution to my problem. You can have a look to my answer. :)